# Read the WebView content(HTML) after response

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm trying to read the `HTML` content of `WebView` after response...
Following is my code, can anyone please tell me why its not working?

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

class MyJavaScriptInterface
{
    @JavascriptInterface
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void processContent(String aContent)
    {
        final String content = aContent;
    }
}
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "document.body.innerHTML");

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
    {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }
});

if (DetailsModel != null)
{
    SimpleDateFormat sdfTime = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyyHHmm");
    Calendar nowCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    String date = sdfTime.format(nowCal.getTime());
    String Note = apref.getMemberNumber();

 HtmlData = "<html><head><script language='JAVASCRIPT'>function 

PostFormCheckOut(){document.FormCheckOut.submit();};</script></head><body onLoad='PostFormCheckOut();'><form name='FormCheckOut' method='POST' action='" + DetailsModel.getsUrl() + "/Clear.asp'><input type='hidden' name='CustomerID' value='" + DetailsModel.getsCustomerID() + "' /><input type='hidden' name='TransactionCurrency' value='" + DetailsModel.getsTransactionCurrency() + "' /><input type='hidden' name='TransactionAmount' value='" + DetailsModel.getsTransactionAmount() + "' /><input type='hidden' name='Notes' value='(" + DetailsModel.getsNote() + ")' /><input type='hidden' name='CustomerEmail' value='" + DetailsModel.getsCustomerEmail() + "' maxlength='50' /><input type='hidden' name='RedirectorSuccess' value='https://***.****.com/***/***.asp' /><input type='hidden' name='RedirectorFailed' value='https://***.****.com/***/***.asp' /><input type='hidden' name='HouseNumber' value='' /><input type='hidden' name='PostCode' value='' /></form><b><font color='red' size='2'>Please wait transferring to a page.</font></b><br/><br/></body></html>";
    webView.loadData(HtmlData, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: You never called `processContent` method. why ? plus you never never explained what is `not working` how would we figure that out ?

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain I don't know how to use `processContent `and I want to read `WebView` content.

Comment: You need full html body right ?

Comment: yes!, but thanks for your previous comment got the answer with its help.. :)